# Ubuntu bash script - Searching all folders to run Video Conversion

Tags: bash, shell, ubuntu

I've recently gotten my hands on a Google Chromecast and realised that almost none of my current media will work "well" with it (most is mkv with ac3 audio)

I've been able to create a simple bash script to convert all files in a folder... but I have hundreds of folders so I'm looking to make this job recursive so I only need to run it once

Current script

```
for i in *.mkv; do
avconv -i "$i" -c:v copy -c:a aac -strict experimental "${i/.mkv/.mp4}"
done
```

What I want to do is add logic to this so that it can search through two sub folders, convert the found file, move the converted file to the root directory and remove the original file

ie

```
 /Movies/convert.script
 /Movies/Movie1/this_movie.mkv
 /Movies/Movie2/that_movie.mkv
 /Movies/Movie3/another_movie.mkv
```

becomes

```
 /Movies/convert.script
 /Movies/this_movie.mp4
 /Movies/that_movie.mp4
 /Movies/another_movie.mp4
```

Answer (score 2):

To search through subfolders you can use `find`

```
find -name '*.mkv' -exec /path/to/convert-movie.sh {} \;
```

where /path/to/convert-movie.sh would be

```
#!/bin/bash
avconv -i "$1" -c:v copy -c:a aac -strict experimental "${1/.mkv/.mp4}"
```